# How to get a specific custom converter from DozerBeanMapperFactoryBean?

Tags: java, spring

I am working on a particular task which consisters of different phases.  In the first phase I created a class(a) that reads a property file and saves the data into a hashmap.  This class has a method (1) that will get the key and return the corresponding value from the map, if there is no entry in the map the key enter will be returned.
In the second phase I created a custom converter class (b)the extends the DozerConverter class I then autowired class (a) and in the method convertTo() that is provided by the DozerConverter class I simpley call the method (1) of class (a).
Since I am using Spring I have used the following code

```
@Bean
public DozerBeanMapperFactoryBean configDozer() throws IOException {
    DozerBeanMapperFactoryBean mapper = new DozerBeanMapperFactoryBean();
    mapper.setCustomConverters(Collections.<CustomConverter> singletonList(new ErrorCodeConverter()));
    return mapper;
}
```

The part that I am confused about is how can I get the ErrorCodeConverter from the mapper object and use this class which is my custom converter.  I have found lots of examples where they provide xml mappings but I don't want any xml mapping.  This job is being done for me by class (a).  I have wrapped class (a) with custom converter to make using of dozzer mapper api.
Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I just take a look in Dozer code from my local (5.3.1), it appears Dozer is designed to apply Custom Converter at 'field' level not 'class' level through API.

You can tweak a bit which wrap your object as a field of another class so you can use API to perform CustomConverter. Hope it helps.

Nghia